# Golang auto-including extensible application

Tags: design-patterns, go

I am fairly new to Go and am curious if there is an established design pattern for extensible applications.

For example, in my source I have an extensions directory where I place different application specific extensions for my program.  I currently load each in my main function individually by name.  I would like to have the program auto-include my extensions when it gets compiled.

Just to be clear, I am not trying to dynamically load extensions at runtime.  I would just like to make adding an extension to the program as simple as:

1. Drop file in extensions folder
2. Recompile

If this is just not possible with Go then I'll make due, but I'm just thinking there has to be a better way to do this.

To show more clearly what I want to make simpler, here is an example of what I do now:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "gopath/project/extensions"
)

func main() {
    app := martini.Classic()

    // Enable Each Extension
    app.Router.Group("/example", extensions.Example)
 // app.Router.Group("/example2", extensions.Example2)
 // ...


    app.Run()
}
```

extensions/example.go

```
package extensions

import (
    "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/render"
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
)

func Example(router martini.Router) {
    router.Get("", func(r render.Render) {
        // respond to query
        r.JSON(200, "")
    })
}
```

Comment: put the package under a subdirectory of your module path and import your submodule into main. But you need to add a standard package name to all of your 'extensions' and handle name conflicts etc ... a nightmare :D

Comment: Another approach is to use RPC like Packer does: http://www.packer.io/docs/extend/developing-plugins.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `init` method in each extension go file to register the extension.

So in `plugin1.go` you'd write

```
func init() {
    App.Router.Group("/example", extensions.Example)
}
```

You'd need to make `app` public.

You could use a registration function in the main code instead.

I use this technique in [rclone](http://rclone.org): [Here is the registration function](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/blob/master/fs/fs.go#L50) and [here is an example of it being called](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/blob/master/s3/s3.go#L25).  The modules are each compiled in [by including them in the main pacakge](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/blob/master/rclone.go#L18)

Comment: Thank you for this!  I completely forgot that init() existed for Go packages.